# Introduction to groups - question/proof check

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, abelian-groups

Prove if the following are abelian groups, if so, list the neutral element e:

(a) $G:= \Bbb Z, a*b:= max \{a,b\}$ (Z as in positive integers incl. zero (i dont know how to write it with mathjax)) 
(b) $G:= \Bbb R, a*b:= a^b$ (only positive real numbers)
(c) $G:= \Bbb Z, a*b:= lcm(a,b)$ (least common multiple of a and b) (integers greater than zero)
(d) G is the open interval $(0,1) \subset \Bbb R $ with
$$x*y: = \frac{xy}{1-(x+y)+2y} $$

Hi guys, the university only gave me some definitions, no further explaination whatsoever, im not even sure i understand this correctly (uni is really terrible at teaching)

First, take example a), I assume "$G:= \Bbb Z, a*b:= max \{a,b\}$ " means a group G with the elements a and b $\subset \Bbb Z $. So i need to use the 4 definitions to prove this to be a abelian group.

**EDIT:**
2) (b) $G:= \Bbb R, a*b:= a^b$

**Associativity**: $\forall a,b,c \in G: a\circ(b\circ c) = (a\circ b)\circ c$ For question b would mean $a^{b^c}=a^{b^c}$ which is correct...

**Invertibility**:$\forall a \in G \exists a' \in G: a' \circ a = e$ Suppose its invertible -> $a'\circ a=e \rightarrow a^{-1^{a}}=e$ However, i do see from my schools paper that $a \circ a^1=e$ should also hold, but then in this case that would be $a^{a^{-1}}$ which is not the same thing, so *invertibility also fails?*

**Identity**: $\forall a \in G: e \circ a = a$ Since invetibility fails i cant say much about identity...

**Commutativity**: $a \circ b = b \circ a$ $\rightarrow a^b=b^a$, unless a=b=1, that is not true either...

If someone has time to look it over and give me some suggestions or point out where is wrong or how to write the proofs more formally id be really thankfull!!!!

Comment: If you think that your university's teaching is hard, one book I would recommend is John E. Gallian Contemporary Abstract Algebra. It is practically written for dummies (like me).

Comment: Are you really sure that an actual mathematics professor used $\mathbb{Z}$ to denote the *positive* integers? I know that notations can vary, but I have never, ever, seen anyone use $\mathbb{Z}$ for anything other than the relative integers.

Comment: @CaptainLama he didnt teach that,,i just dont know how to use latex to write positive integers,,,

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes unfortunetely i wouldnt have the time, they cover this extremely quickly, 2 lectures and move on

Comment: @JerryCohen, the good thing about the book is it's simplicity. An hour with the first chapter about Groups will do wonders. A lot of Abstract Algebra is understanding the basic Axioms first, then merely expanding from there.

Comment: @JerryCohen Ok, then the correct notation is $\mathbb{N}$, as in *natural* numbers (depending on the authors it might include $0$ or not, so it's a good thing to make it clear). The notation $\mathbb{Z}$ (coming from the German word "Zahl" meaning number) refers to relative integers, ie including the negative ones.

Comment: The operation in question (b) is NOT associative. Just look at $(2\wedge 3)\wedge 2$ versus $2\wedge (3\wedge 2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the operation (which is often called multiplication for Groups). When we say we multiply 2 elements $a$,$b$ in a group, we mean we do the group operation "$\circ$" for $a$ and $b$. That is, $a \circ b$.

For example, The real numbers form an abelian group $G$, with operation $a \circ b = (a+2)+(b+2)$ (regular addition as a *part* of the operation)

1. **Associativity**: $(a \circ b) \circ c = \left((a+2) + (b+2)\right) \circ c = (a+b+4) \circ c = (a+b+4)+(c+2) = a+b+c+6 = a \circ (b+c+4) = a \circ \left((b+2)+(c+2) \right) = a \circ (b \circ c)$.
2. **Identity**: Does there exist an element $e$, such that $a \circ e = a$? Let $a$ be chosen randomly from the elements of $G$, and let $x=-4$. Notice that $a \circ x = (a+2) + (x+2) = (a+2) + (-4+2) = a$. Thus we can deduce that $e=-4$.
3. **Invertibility** Does there exist an element $a^{-1}$, such that $a \circ a^{-1} = e$? This is the same as solving $(a+2)+(a^{-1}+2)=-4$, which gives us $a^{-1}=-a-8$. Once more, since we can choose $a$ randomly (or "arbitrarily") from the elements of $G$, that means all elements of $G$ has an inverse!

It can also be shown that our group $\left(G,\circ\right)$ is commutative, however I don't want to put it there, because it is not necessary to form a group. The one thing I want to emphasize is that we are not *multiplying* (unless the operation is a literal multiplication) anything, but rather using the group operation. In your question, you apply the group operation first, then multiply it again.

If you would like, I can also point out why/why not (a),(b),(c),(d) are groups.

Comment: aha so its similiar to relations

Comment: So question a wouldnt hold as a group? since $a\circ (b \circ c) $is not equal to $(a\circ b)\circ c$.  Because a might be greater than b but there is no way to determine a is greater than c?

Comment: @JerryCohen for question (a), no matter the order of operation, we can guarantee that by doing $a \circ b \circ c$, the answer is the max(a,b,c). However it is not a group due to another reason! Suppose it has an identity $e$. Let us check it's invertibility. Assume it is invertible, max($a$,$a^{-1}$) = $e$. Then, either $e=a$ or $e=a^{-1}$. If the former, then every element of the group is an identity (wrong! only one identity in a group). If the latter, then $e > a$. But then, max($a$,$e$) = $e$, not $a$! (remember that by definition identity is the element such that $a \circ e=a$

Comment: Thanks a became very clear !  If you have time could you have look at my edits? Thanks

Comment: It is not commutative yes, that is enough to show that it is not an Abelian group. And yes, for any element $a \in G$, $e \circ a = a = a \circ e$

Comment: if you have time could you quickly explain what the last question 4d) meant by open interval between 0 and 1? Does that mean x*y is only within 0 andn 1, i mean i could do the all four group axioms but i dont know what that means that the thing. is between 0 and 1....if you could quckly touch on that

Comment: I opened a new post to ask that question and got. really distroyed by people for doing that.,....but i really still have absolutely 0 idea what that means

Comment: The closed interval [0,1] includes all points between 0 and 1 INCLUDING 0 and 1. The open interval (0,1) includes all points between 0 and 1 EXCLUDING 0 and 1.